# LINQ: Group By, and retrieve common property

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following dataset, which is stored in a variable called list1.

```
countrypk | countryname | statepk | statename
---------------------------------------------
1           USA           1         New York
1           USA           2         California
2           Canada        3         Manitoba
```

I want to be able to group by countrypk, and retrieve the country name.

I have the following LINQ that achieves that effect, but was wondering if there was a better or more straight forward way to do it in LINQ.

```
var finalList = list1
    .GroupBy(item => item.countrypk)
    .Where(item => item.Count() > 0)
    .Select(item => item.First())
```

The desired output is:

```
countrypk | countryname 
---------------------------------------------
1           USA                  
2           Canada
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? It seems like `countrypk` is unique so it won't help grouping by it. Please show desired output

Comment: I Fixed my post.

Comment: It seems like all you need is just getting 2 out of the 4 columns but no grouping. Is that what you need?

Comment: You are full of good questions. I fixed the post. The desired output is 2 rows, with 2 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of the `Where` is not needed. If you have a group it contains at least a single item in it. You can do something like this:

```
list1.GroupBy(item => item.countrypk)
     .Select(item => new { item.Key, item.First().countryname} );
```

Or using a different overload of `GroupBy`:

```
list1.GroupBy(item => item.countrypk, 
              selector => new { selector.countrypk, selector.countryname} )
     .Select(group => group.First())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the GroupBy overload, is it grouping by item followed by selector?

Comment: @user2769810 - you can read more on MSDN but basically it's the equivalent for the query syntax of `group /*the selector -what data to group*/ by /*the key*/ into g`

Answer (score 0):

If you grouped by countrypk, your result set wouldn't have duplicates in it.  Your desired result set has duplicate countrypk values in it (1).  To get your desired result set, do this:

```
var finalList = list1.Select(s => new { s.countrypk, s.countryname });
```

Edit: nevermind this part above, OP editted the question.

---

`I want to be able to group by countrypk, and retrieve the country name` What you're asking for is different than what your result set shows.  If you want a map of countrypk to country name using your `list1`, here's one way to do it:

```
var finalList = list1
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.countrypk, g.countryname })
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key.countrypk, v => v.Key.countryname);
```

Note that you don't need `GroupBy` to do this.  Here's another solution:

```
var finalList = list1
    .Select(s => new { s.countrypk, s.countryname })
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(k => k.countrypk, v => v.countryname);
```

In either case, to get the country name for id 1, do this:

```
var countryName = finalList[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var finalList = list1
    .GroupBy(item => item.countrypk)
    .Select(g => new { countrypk = g.Key, countryname = g.First().countryname });
```

which should provided the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to remove duplicates by countrypk and select only first two columns? Use this extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        HashSet<TResult> set = new HashSet<TResult>();

        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            var selectedValue = selector(item);

            if (set.Add(selectedValue))
                yield return item;
        }
    }
```

And then

```
var finalList = list1
    .DistinctBy(item => item.countrypk)
    .Select(item=> new {item.countrypk, item.countryname })
    .ToList();
```